# VBA script to automatically open results from google search in chrome

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

I have found the following code which works for me:

```
Sub SearchWindow64()
Dim chromePath As String
Dim search_string As String
Dim query As String
query = Range("A2").Value
search_string = query
search_string = Replace(search_string, " ", "+")

chromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Shell (chromePath & " -url http://google.com/#q=" & search_string)
End Sub
```

It opens my Google Chrome and navigates to google and does a search based on the value of cell A2.
So far so good, but I would also like my script to open the first or the second result(this to also be specified by the user) - for example if the value in cell A3 is 1 to open the first result, if its 2 - the second result and so on..

I have found solutions for similar problems for Internet Explorer, but I want to do this in Google Chrome, can anyone help on this?

Regards,
Mihail

Comment: Look into [tag:selenium]

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to do it with just vba macro

Comment: IE solutions use an API that can talk to IE. Chrome solutions use an API that can talk to Chrome. See [VBA+Selenium posts on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba+selenium) for a bunch of working examples.

Answer (score 0):

In case you try the selenium vba route; which is still written using vba. The following excludes the "People also ask" section (as well as anything not starting with "http")

```
Option Explicit
'Download selenium https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0
'Ensure latest applicable driver e.g. ChromeDriver.exe in Selenium folder
'VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to selenium type library
Public Sub Example()
    Dim d As WebDriver, ws As Worksheet, search_string As String, query As String
    Dim resultToOpen As Long, results As Object, final()
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    query = ws.Range("A2").Value
    search_string = query
    search_string = Replace$(search_string, " ", "+")
    resultToOpen = ws.Range("A3").Value

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get "http://google.com/#q=" & search_string

        Set results = .FindElementsByCss("cite")

        final = GetUsuableLinks(results)
        If UBound(final) >= resultToOpen Then
            .get final(resultToOpen)
        Else
            'do something else
        End If

        Stop   'delete me later

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetUsuableLinks(ByVal results As Object) As Variant
    Dim arr(), i As Long, j As Long, test As String
    ReDim arr(1 To results.Count)
    For i = 1 To results.Count
        test = results(i).Text
        If InStr(test, "http") > 0 Then
            j = j + 1
            arr(j) = test
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arr(1 To j)
    GetUsuableLinks = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try this?